# Display something upon a change to a BooleanField in a django database in django app

Tags: ajax, django, jquery-ajaxq, django-ajax-selects

I have an uber like django app. A customer can signal that they are looking for someone to provide a service and people in the same area who are looking to be service providers can view a list of actively seeking customers. When the customer presses the button signaling they are looking for a service, they are redirected to a page that says "Thank you, you will be notified when someone is on the way" and it sets attribute `active` to `True`. This displays them on the previously mentioned list where customers can be 'claimed.' When a service provider claims a customer. I want the customer's page to display 'Someone will be there shortly" or something of that nature. But how can I let the customer's page (customer_active.html) know that `active` has been set to `False`(ie they have been claimed) and then display a message on the occurrence of that event? I have read about potentially using django signals or ajax/jquery but I do not know what the right route is nor how to implement the solution in said route. I have the following code:

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Profile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    active = models.BooleanField(default = False)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    #home 
    url(r'^home/$', views.home, name = 'home'),

    #/claim/user_id
    url(r'^claim/(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.ClaimView.as_view(), name = "claim"),


    #/active
    url(r'^active/$', views.customer_active, name='customer_active'),


]    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

customer_active.html (the customer is looking at this after they signal they are looking for the service):

```
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}

{% block head %}

    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'core/customer_active.css' %}">

    <title>Active</title>
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
        <div class="container text-center">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
                    <h1 class="lead">Thank you, {{ user.first_name}} {{user.last_name }}, you will be alerted
                    when someone claims your laundry</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


{% endblock %}
```

home.html:

```
{% for customer in customers%}
                            <tr>
                                <td style = "text-align:center">{{ customer.user.first_name|title }} {{ customer.user.last_name|title }}</td>
                                <td style = "text-align:center">{{ customer.user.profile.address|title }}</td>
                                <td style = "text-align:center"><a href="{% url 'claim' user_id=customer.user.id %}">Claim</a></td>
                            </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

views.py:

```
#the service provider that claimed a customer gets redirected to 'claim.html', upon this 'active' gets set to False
class ClaimView(View):
    def get(self, request, user_id, *args, **kwargs):
        customer = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
        customer.profile.active = False
        customer.save()
        return render(request, 'core/claim.html', {'customer': customer})

def customer_active(request):
    request.user.profile.active = True;
    request.user.save()
    return render(request, 'core/customer_active.html', {'user': request.user})
```

How can I use ajax/jquery to display a message saying 'Someone will be there shortly" in customer_active.html upon a service provider claiming the customer?

Answer (score 0):

So.. if a customer is in customer_active.html page, when service provider claims the customer, the customer should be alerted in customer_active.html page. If I have perceived the problem correctly, then it is a matter of creating a timer that will send Ajax calls every few seconds to check if a service provider has claimed the customer.

```
    setInterval(function(){
        minAjax({
           url:"/serviceprovider/",//request URL
           type:"GET",//Request type GET/POST
           //CALLBACK FUNCTION with RESPONSE as argument
           success: function(data){
               //check if someone has claimed
               if (data == true){
                   alert("Someone will be there shortly");
               }
           }
       });
     }, 5000); //5000 represents 5 seconds
```

Views.py

```
@login_required
def serviceprovider(request):
    claimed=False
    claim=Model.objects.filter(user=User.objects.get(username=request.user), claimed=True)
    if claim:
       claimed=True
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(claimed))
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^serviceprovider/', views.serviceprovider, name = 'serviceprovider'),
```

You need [minAjax](http://flouthoc.github.io/minAjax.js/) for this to work, it is a very small library using pure javascript. Just download the library and put it in your js folder, and import it. I haven't tested the above example but I have used this method in a project and it works. This is just to guide you to the right direction. Good luck!

Comment: this sounds like exactly what I need, but I am confused on the 'data' parameter, what is this exactly and when is it getting passed into the function?

Comment: @JustinO'Brien `data` is the data being returned from the backend. So in the above case, `data` is `claimed` from `views.py`. Umm